# How to change first name that shows at appstoreconnect.apple.com

Tags: apple-id, app-store-connect, developer-program

When I log into https://appstoreconnect.apple.com, the name that shows up in the top right corner, `Mary Doe`, is wrong. However, when I click a link to go to a different page within that subdomain like https://appstore.connect.apple.com/apps I can see that my changes to the name I'd expect, `John Doe`. Here are some examples.

`Mary` in top right corner for https://appstoreconnect.apple.com
[image]

`John` in top right corner for https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/apps
[image]

The name `John Doe` is what should always be there and when I go to other Apple subdomains like https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage, I can see the name is `John Doe` for my Apple ID and this is the case in other Apple subdomains.

[image]

Another case where the name shows up as `Mary Doe` is if I go to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/access/users and look for the name associated with my Apple ID but that name doesn't show up in other cases like signing into an iPhone with my Apple ID. The name that shows on the phone is what I'd expect, `John Doe`.

Does anyone know where I need to go to update the first name from `Mary` to `John` or do I have to contact Apple?